# Excel filter pivot between two values (fast)

Tags: excel, pivot, vba

I want to filter according to a field ("QTD bill %") to get all values for which  0,3< "QTD bill %" <0,35 with VBA :

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim pvtF As PivotField
Dim pvtI As PivotItem

Set pvtF = Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables(1).PivotFields("QTD bill %")
For Each pvtI In pvtF.PivotItems
    If pvtI > "0.3" And pvtI < "0.35" Then
        pvtI.Visible = True
    Else
        pvtI.Visible = False
    End If
Next pvtI

End Sub
```

But when I run the code it takes >1min!!!

How can I filter between two values fast?

Help me please!! Thank you

Comment: It would be more easier if you could simply add a new column with a calculated field like"if value between 0,3 and 0,35 then 'yes' else 'no'"

Comment: Thank you for your proposition. I am afraid this would be the only solution, because it means i would have to fabricate a filter from scratch and not use the functions already provided which should make it a lot more easier. This would make the process very tough as I have a lot of data and would have to update it each time.

Comment: Try to move the calculated field to rows and then create groups according to the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the "Values filter" option from one of the dropdowns you see on the other non-Values PivotField to filter any fields that are in the VALUES area.

See this screenshot from the book I'm writing that illustrates this:
[image]