# Excel Pivot filtering on calculated fields

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, calculated-columns

Calculated fields are awesome BUT there are restrictions such as not being able to sort through it (impossible to move the field to the Report Filters area).

I have tried "forcing" a filter like Microsoft's guys suggested : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/filtering-a-pivot-table-on-a-calculated-field/31312a31-8e9a-401b-acb0-ed575d9cb397 but it appeared to be a very bad idea.

So instead, I tried sorting using VBA with my code here : [Excel filter pivot between two values (fast)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236773/excel-filter-pivot-between-two-values-from-a-calculated-field)
but it didn't work on the calculated field either.

How to use a calculated field just like any regular field?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select the "Values filter" option from one of the dropdowns you see on the other non-Values PivotField to filter any fields that are in the VALUES area. 
[image]

Comment: Amazing tip!! Thank you a lot!! Works well but unfortunately Slicers and Values in Filters don't update accordingly